# How to add icon to the enumerate field?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, icons, strapi, enumerate

I'm beginner in strapi and i can't add icon to the 'enumerate' field.

What should i do to add an icon to the ecah line against the name, like a:
IconTelegram telegram
IconInstagram instagram
Please help)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeg0q.png)